# How to create a custom keyboard with Gif images in Android? Any Tutorial or sample source please?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, android-keypad, custom-keyboard

How to create a custom keyboard with Gif images in Android? I need to create a custom keyboard which contains Gif  images ,I need to develop a keyboard like the below image ,Any Tutorial or sample source please?

[I need to develop a keyboard like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig94m.jpg)

Comment: you can follow this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: @Anjali I already followed the tutorial but i need the key board like the picture in the link : I need to develop a keyboard like this